# How to redirect to new page in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to learn React and I'm struggling to redirect to the page where it shows the details about the clicked item. I have added the react-router-dom but I don't know where to go from here.

My brewery.js

```
import React from "react";

class Brewery extends React.Component {
 render() {
const name = `${this.props.brewery.name} - ${this.props.brewery.city}`;
 return <div>{name}</div>
 }
}

export default Brewery;
```

My app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Brewery from './components/brewery'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      breweries: []
    };
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          breweries: data,
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
            {this.state.breweries.map((brewery) => {
              return <Brewery key={brewery.name} brewery={brewery}/>
          })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with below:

```
import { BrowserRouter,Route,Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Now wrap you app.js in index.js with BrowserRouter like:

```
<BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>
```

You have router in you project. now define routes

```
<Switch><Route path="/" component={Home}/></Switch>
```

So whenever you type "/" Home component will load.

If you want to move to new page use props.history.push('/profile');. This will redirect you to profile page.